# Releasing root view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have the following statement inside

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

The statement is :

```
root_view_controller = [[Root_View_Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Base_View" bundle : nil];
```

I am not using ARC, so I am thinking of releasing root_view_controller in

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

My question is : Is the above practice ok ?   And : Is there any other clean up code that should be added before releasing root_view_controller ?

Comment: When the application is terminating it ll automatically release all the objects. So no need to do anything. Still if you do then also it has no problem.

Comment: [UIWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) retains its `rootViewController`, ARC or not you can (and most probably should) let the windows release it. Keep in mind not to over-retain viewController yourself though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Just wish to clarify.  UIWindow retains its rootViewController, but it will also release the view controller.  But initWithNibName would give the controller an initial r count 1.  So there would still be a r count left.  Just that ios would take care of that if we don't do it.  Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[MLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MLViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

If you want release your Root_View_Controller you need to do it in dealloc method like the code above

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Guess you have answered my question.  applicationWillTerminate didn't feel quite right which is one of the reasons the question is posted. Must have seen it in document some time ago but my memory is rusty. Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to release memory in

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

because when an app is terminated, the memory it used is released anyway.

Comment: this is something i was just writing,... anyway, i would release it anyway, for the sake of my ocd :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Do you mean that it is ok not to release root_view_controller at all (even without ARC) ?

Comment: Yes, it is ok not to release memory in applicationWillTerminate: at all

Comment: There is a good reason and it's very good practice to release memory that you use despite all memory being freed on termination.  That reason is that you can instrument your app for memory leaks and you won't pick up objects that you intend to just be destroyed on termination.

Comment: Guess I have some sort of ocd myself. Or just for the sake of completeness. Cthutu, thanks for pointing out about the memory instrument. Thank you all for your kind assistance...